# Why can't I connect to server via actual public IP?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

I am new in network programming and I try to do echo client and server. It works properly via localhost (127.0.0.1) and 192.168.1.35, but doesn't via my actual IP. So it's impossible to connect to my server across the Internet. However, I checked it in my local network and it worked.
You can try [client](http://rghost.ru/53939771). If connection is done, client display an appropriate message. There are two clients. For IP 192.168.1.35 and for my actual IP, which I can get by [such](http://www.whatismyip.com/) and similar services. There are several libs which should be located in the same directory as `exe`.

And one more question. What does my server display by these lines?

```
tcp::endpoint ep = *iter++;
std::cout << ep << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
[fe80::5100:812f:ad7c:a6dc%13]:0
192.168.1.35:0
```

I just wanted to get my IP and the second one is an IP, though it is local. But what is first one?
Thank you!

I use MSVS 2013, Boost::Asio, Windows 7.
Here is the code:
**server.cpp**

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using boost::system::error_code;

io_service service;
size_t read_complete(char * buff, const error_code & err, size_t bytes) {
    if (err) return 0;
    bool found = std::find(buff, buff + bytes, '\n') < buff + bytes;
    // we read one-by-one until we get to enter, no buffering
    return found ? 0 : 1;
}

void handle_connections() {
    ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), 8001));
    char buff[1024];
    while (true) {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
        acceptor.accept(sock);
        int bytes = read(sock, buffer(buff),
            boost::bind(read_complete, buff, _1, _2));
        std::string msg(buff, bytes);
        sock.write_some(buffer(msg));
        sock.close();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::host_name(), "");
    tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::resolver::iterator end; // End marker.
    while (iter != end)
    {
        tcp::endpoint ep = *iter++;
        std::cout << ep << std::endl;
    }
    handle_connections();
}
```

**client.cpp**

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <stdio.h>
#endif


#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
io_service service;

size_t read_complete(char * buf, const error_code & err, size_t bytes) {
    if (err) return 0;
    bool found = std::find(buf, buf + bytes, '\n') < buf + bytes;
    // we read one-by-one until we get to enter, no buffering
    return found ? 0 : 1;
}

//ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 8001);
ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string("192.168.1.35"), 8001);
void sync_echo(std::string msg) {
    msg += "\n";
    ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
    sock.connect(ep);
    sock.write_some(buffer(msg));
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes = read(sock, buffer(buf), boost::bind(read_complete, buf, _1, _2));
    std::string copy(buf, bytes - 1);
    msg = msg.substr(0, msg.size() - 1);
    std::cout << "server echoed our " << msg << ": "
        << (copy == msg ? "OK" : "FAIL") << std::endl;
    sock.close();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // connect several clients
    char* messages[] = { "John says hi", "so does James",
        "Lucy just got home", "Boost.Asio is Fun!", 0 };
    boost::thread_group threads;
    for (char ** message = messages; *message; ++message) {
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(sync_echo, *message));
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(100));
    }
    threads.join_all();

    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
}
```

Comment: I was confused by the 92.168.1.35 but now I realize you probably mean 192.168.1.35?

Comment: Yes, sorry. In the program I used correct IP.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16002005/1053968) answer contains some general networking related issues and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to your PC from outside LAN to port 8001 you have to open this port in router and tell your router what to do with the incoming connection on port 8001. If your router public IP is 92.168.1.35 and you are listening on local PC 192.168.1.35 on port 8001, then you have to open your router configuration page in Web browser, go to Port Forwarding/ Port Triggering and establish a forwarding of port 8001 of your router to 192.168.1.35 8001. Also make sure your server listens on 0.0.0.0 ( `INADDR_ANY` in C code) not on your LAN interface.

After this you can check if application is listening on port 8001:

```
sudo netstat -anlpl | grep 8001
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer.  
I forwarded the port, but it still doesn't work. Firewall is shut down.  
How to check if server listen on 0.0.0.0? `acceptor.local_endpoint().address()` returns 0.0.0.0 before any conections with socket. Is it right?

Comment: sudo netstat -anlpl | grep 8001

Comment: If I don't open 8001 port, client immediately crashes. But when I does, it runs for a while with no output and then anyway crashes.

Comment: does it crash only when connecting via public IP or on LAN too?

Comment: try telnet 192.168.1.35 8001, try then telnet PUBLIC_IP 8001. compare

Comment: you said it crashes, what it means? what exactly happens, we need details if you want us to help you

Comment: No problems. It does nothing for about 5-10 sec, then a standard windows error occurs. Name of event: "APPCRASH".

Comment: this is related to the threading, not IPs, and threading part is not in your example. Try simpler version, 1 thread, if it works create multithreaded version

Comment: I have no other parts. Only 2 files. I tried version with 1 thread and all the same: works with local IP, and doesn't with public.

Comment: It turned out, that all worked. The reason is I can't connect to my own IP. At my friend's PC client works properly. Thanks!

Comment: why you cannot connect to your IP?

Comment: I read on a forum some routers or providers don't allow to connect to own external IP. This http://canyouseeme.org/ service sees my server on 8001 port. So asked my friend to try the client.

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to get my IP and the second one is an IP, though it is local. But what is first one?

The first one is your ipv6 address

The reason it doesn't work "externally" is likely routing or firewalling.

Make sure port <strike>13</strike>8001 is routed to your machine and not blocked.

Comment: why 13? OP connects on 8001

Comment: Oh. Right. Daytime usually listens on 13. Correcting